# Java Trying to use Period class to get the difference between 2 dates, keep getting Period cannot be resolve to a type

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a countdown timer.  I was going to use the  Period class to get the difference between 2 GregorianCalendar Dates.

I keep getting a Period cannot be resolve to a type error. I'm assuming this is becouse I need another import.
I did the following
   Change my import from java.util.GregorianCalendar to import java.util.*;
   TRy to add import java.util.Period;, which gave a error

This must be a easy fix, just cant get it to work.

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of the Period class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class cannot be resolved to a type because the class is not delivered in the jre you are using. And from what I see, it is definetely not included in the java.util package ([java 6 util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html), [java 7 util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html)).
I saw that a *Period* class is offered in the  [Joda library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html). There is a [similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances) on stackoveflow, maybe it can be useful for you.